# Inverse Standardization

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, statistics

If I standarized my dataset with

```
data= (data- data.rolling(WINDOW).mean())/data.rolling(WINDOW).std()
```

and make a prediction, how can I unstandardize my prediction to fit back into the original data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep track of the mean and standard deviation

```
r = data.rolling(WINDOW).agg(['mean', 'std'])
data = (data - r.mean) / r.std

pred = some_function_that_gives_predictions(data)

pred * r.std + r.mean
```

Comment: May I please clarify, if your prediction is out of time, let say for t+1, you're still using mean and standard deviation, computed on the *prior* WINDOW points?